# Create 1080p videos with javacv and ffmpeg or alternate lib

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, video-capture, video-processing, javacv

is  there a option in JavaCV to capture 1080p videos from images?
If i use the `FFmpegFrameRecorde`, i only find 480p.

Or is there a alternate library for Java?
I want to use it to create a video from kind of pictures (with zooming and rotating effects)

greetings

//EDIT

Okay,
now i've tested a very simple code:

```
    FrameRecorder  recorder = FFmpegFrameRecorder.createDefault("out.avi", 1920, 1080);
    recorder.start();
    recorder.record(iplImage);
    recorder.stop();
```

and it's works! But the file is very large (10sec around 300MB...)

Now i want to add a codec like xvid. I've get the following eyxception:

```
com.googlecode.javacv.FrameRecorder$Exception: codec not found
```

But i've installed the xvid paket. Must i add the codec in a special folder like the ffmpeg bin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay,
now i test the mp4 codec and all works fine :)

//UPDATE

**for JavaCV 0.2**

```
    FrameRecorder recorder = FFmpegFrameRecorder.createDefault("out.avi", 1920, 1080);
    recorder.setCodecID(CODEC_ID_MPEG4);
    recorder.setPixelFormat(PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
    recorder.start();
            .....
    recorder.stop();
```

**for JavaCV 0.3**

```
    FrameRecorder recorder = FFmpegFrameRecorder.createDefault("out.avi", 1920, 1080);
    recorder.setVideoCodec(CODEC_ID_MPEG4);
    recorder.setFrameRate(fps);
    recorder.setFormat("avi");
    recorder.start();
            .....
    recorder.stop();
```

Comment: hi,i m getting error in this line (CODEC_ID_MPEG4).is there any package need to import?

Comment: @rams this code is for the javacv0.2 version. Maybe you use 0.3? (See update)

Comment: ok can i know how to use javacv in android.is there any simple sample?

Comment: @501-notimplemented I have javacv-1.0 what code to use in this case?